# Calculate Balance in Date range - PouchDB

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

i am working on small billing application
i want to calculate the opening balance for the date range

i have following fields in docs of pouch db data base

date:2021-08-01 
sale:800
invest:500
expense: 100

i want to calculate the opening balance by date range using pouchdb

opening balance will be previous date closing balance

calculation will be -> **closing = ( opening+investment+sale ) - exp**

This table is example to calculate the balance for each day

```
date        opening     sale        invest     exp    closing
2020-03-01  0           100.00      10.00      0      90.00
2020-03-02  90.00       50.00       20.00      0      120.00     
2020-03-02  120.0       100.00       0.00      0      220.00
2020-03-03  220.00      200.00      20.00      0      400.00  
2020-03-04  400.00      110.00      10.00      10     110.00
```

```js
// onchange function
function getday(){

    // ---------------------------------------------opening---------------------------------------------
    var opening_balance = 0
    function daysale(n){
    
        daybook.find({
            selector: {
                
                Date:n ,
            
            }
        }).then(function(result) {  
            
           
        
            //chenking the data is present in  the selected date 
            if(result.docs.length>0){

                result.docs.forEach((element, ) => {

                    saletotal = (isNaN(element.TotalAmount) ? 0: parseInt(element.TotalAmount));
                    Totalinvest = (isNaN(element.TotalInvestment) ? 0: parseInt(element.TotalInvestment));
                    Totalexp = (isNaN(element.TotalExpenses) ? 0: parseInt(element.TotalExpenses));

                    opening_balance+=saletotal+Totalinvest-Totalexp

                
                    document.getElementById('open-balance').value=opening_balance

                    
                });
            } 
            // if there is no data on particular date subtracting one  day from  date from date and calling the 
            //get day function with yesterday value as parameter to check if the data is present in previos date
            else{

                let d = new Date(n);
                d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
                var daybeforedate = d.toISOString().split('T')[0];
                
                //recursion function to calculate the previous date if there is no data in particular date
                daysale(daybeforedate)

            }
            
        });

    }
    // get date value and minus one day 
    var  TodayDate = document.getElementById('daybook-firstdate').value;
    let d = new Date(TodayDate);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
    var yesterdaydate = d.toISOString().split('T')[0];
   
    // function call for current date
    daysale(yesterdaydate)
    
    }
```

```css
input{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="daybookhandle">
       <label>From<input type="date" name="daybook" id="daybook-firstdate" onchange="getday()" ></label>
       <label>To<input type="date" name="daybook" id="daybook-firstdate" onchange="getday()" ></label>
       
       <label>Opening Balance:</label>
        <input type="text" name="balnce" id="open-balance"   >

       <label >Investment : </label>
        <input type="text" name="ivest" id="invest-ment">

       <label >Expenses : </label>
        <input type="text" name="Exp" id="Expense_Total">

      <label >Total Sales : </label>
      <input type="text" name="sale" id="Sales_total">

       <label >Closing Balance :</label>
        <input type="text" name="cbalance" id="closing_balance">
   </div>
```

any one help me with a code
if there is any more doubt please feel free to ask

Comment: What is not working, exactly?

Comment: sorry for late reply i did not try the code for opening balance in range can you help me with code or with any explanation for how to achieve the opening balance in date range using pouch db find

Comment: we define opening balance = 0 for one day for example on `2021-01-01` the opening balance will be = 0 from that  we should calculate the  further opening balances

Comment: So really the question is how to use the `_find` endpoint for a date range?

Comment: Also due to the scope of `opening_balance` it's an ever increasing sum of all documents - shouldn't it be `opening_balance = saletotal+Totalinvest-Totalexp` instead of `opening_balance += saletotal+Totalinvest-Totalexp`?

Comment: okay sir i will try with this